# How to get a Facebook user address and user phone number?

Tags: facebook

I have seen this topic: *[Platform Updates: New User Object fields, Edge.remove Event and More][1]*.

It will get the user address and user phone number. I have tested it, but I got an error:

> Error.
>
> An error occurred with Shopping. Please try again later.
>
> API Error Code: 100
> API Error Description: Invalid parameter
> Error Message: Invalid permission: user_mobile_phone

My URL is:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email,user_birthday,user_mobile_phone&client_id=216841335057887&redirect_uri=http://localhost:63462/SocialMediaData/FaceBook/CallBack.aspx&response_type=token
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 10):

Check out the next [blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/),  - the feature was removed shortly afterwards.

And currently facebook does not in any other way give away the telephone number via the api.